# Get initializer value with TypeScript compiler API

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a simple class that I'm extracting info from using `ts.createSourceFile`:

```
export default class Button extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: [String], required: false }) type!: string
}
```

How can I extract the value `false` from the `required` decorator parameter above?

The below code is fetched by the from the property's `decorators[0].expression.arguments[0].properties` where `escapedText` equals `required`:

```
NodeObject {
  pos: 237,
  end: 253,
  flags: 0,
  modifierFlagsCache: 0,
  transformFlags: 0,
  parent: undefined,
  kind: 279,
  decorators: undefined,
  modifiers: undefined,
  name:
   IdentifierObject {
     pos: 237,
     end: 246,
     flags: 0,
     modifierFlagsCache: 0,
     transformFlags: 0,
     parent: undefined,
     kind: 75,
     escapedText: 'required' },
  questionToken: undefined,
  exclamationToken: undefined,
  initializer:
   TokenObject {
     pos: 247,
     end: 253,
     flags: 0,
     modifierFlagsCache: 0,
     transformFlags: 0,
     parent: undefined,
     kind: 90 } }
```

Where is the `false` value? Should I use the SyntaxKind from `kind`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `prop.initializer.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.TrueKeyword` is sufficent to determine boolean values